# Install fontawesome using angular cli 6.0.5 throws error E418

Tags: angular, font-awesome

After executing command 'npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular' on windows machine I got the error code E418 - I'm a teapot: @fortawesome-free-regular@latest.

Enviroment:

Angular CLI: 6.0.5, Node: 8.9.1, Os: win32 x64 and Angular: 6.0.3

I do not understand the meaning of this error code? Could be a proxy or compatibility between angular and fontawesome version?

```
9 verbose stack Error: 418 I'm a teapot: @fortawesome/fontawesome@latest
9 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\dev\tools\node-v8.9.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
9 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\dev\tools\node-v8.9.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\dev\tools\node-v8.9.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\dev\tools\node-v8.9.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\dev\tools\node-v8.9.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\dev\tools\node-v8.9.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
9 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\dev\tools\node-v8.9.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
9 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\dev\tools\node-v8.9.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
9 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\dev\tools\node-v8.9.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
9 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
9 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
9 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
```

Comment: I found out the issue around this subject. It was related with proxy enabled on .npmrc config file. I change the string 'http' to 'https' for registry property (registry=https://registry.npmjs.org). - reference: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20791

Answer (score 0):

for this error I find that funny, and I could find some  : [explanation of the concept here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-story-behind-HTTP-status-code-418-Im-a-Teapot?share=1).
and the right command to install fortawesome according to the official repos of npm is: `npm i @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome`, or you can use yarn also: `yarn add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome`
you can see how to use it in the code below:

```
<head>
    <!--core first + styles last-->
    <link href="/static/fontawesome/fontawesome-all.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!--user icon in two different styles-->
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    <i class="far fa-user"></i>
    <!--brand icon-->
    <i class="fab fa-github-square"></i>
</body>
```